# What is a dac file, and how do I use it?

Tags: backup, exchange

I have taken backup of mailboxes of exchange server by "Code two" software.There are files generated by it are SDF(.sdf),BAK(.bak),xml and DAC(.dac).I searched so many times ,i haven't got any information regarding DAC(.dac) files.Does anybody has any idea about it?

Comment: I think it's better to backup mailbox via official way: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91

Comment: Actually,i can only take backup from that("code two") software only.